# Refactoring method with multiple Logical ANDs

Tags: ruby

I have a method where I am regularly performing Logical AND on a variable, can it be refactored? This is sort of a 2 part question.

- Is there a short circuit way of doing `var = var && condition`?
- Is there a better way to write this based on multiple conditions and still only return a single boolean?

I'm hoping for something similar to a `+=` kind of thing.

```
def my_method
  var = true

  if condition
    var = var && cond1
  end

  if other_condition
    var = var && cond2
  end

  var
end
```

Comment: you can write all of those `if` statements as one line instead of three:  `var &&= cond1 if condition`

Comment: or `var &= cond1 && cond2`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Is that a typo?  `&=` is bitwise and, not logical

Comment: in your current method, `var` will always assigned the value of `cond1` if `condition` is true and then by `cond2` if `other_conditon` is true and `var` is not falsy. Meaning if for whatever reason `cond1` and `cond2` are not true/false you might not always get a boolean back.

Comment: @WayneConrad I couldn't remember whether it mattered & couldn't find the doc.

Comment: @Leo Did you mean to address that to someone else?  I didn't say anything one way or the other about the OP wanted to return.

Comment: @WayneConrad Nope, I misread your comment :) sorry!

Comment: @WayneConrad although `&` and `|` are bitwise operators they seem to behave as expected with booleans. "The Ruby Programming Language" says on page 105: "Other classes use these operators as well, usually in ways that are compatible with their logical AND, OR, and NOT meanings.". Just learned that you can even use XOR (`^`) with boolean values :) However, the bitwise complement `~` does not work with them.

Comment: @p11y That's extraordinary.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use statement modifiers:

```
def my_method
  res = true
  res &&= cond1 if condition
  res &&= cond2 if other_condition
  res
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the wonderful discussion above and clean answer.

Answer (score 2):

- Is there a short circuit way of doing var = var && condition?

  Yes.

  ```
  var &&= condition
  ```
- Is there a better way to write this based on multiple conditions and still only return a single boolean?

  ```
  def my_method
    (cond1 || !condition      ) &&
    (cond2 || !other_condition)
  end
  ```

  Edit. p11y's comment is right.

  <strike>If you don't like it, you can also write like this using keywords:</strike>

  ```
  def my_method
    (cond1 if condition      ) and
    (cond2 if other_condition)
  end
  ```

Comment: `and` and `&&` are not synonyms. `and` is a control flow operator not a boolean operator.

Comment: @LeoCorrea They have different precedence. So what?

Comment: I'm just commenting on your answer so those that are new coming into ruby don't think that they can/should use `and`/`&&` or `or`/`||` interchangeably.

Comment: @LeoCorrea already said why: Because _and_ is a flow control operator, not a boolean operator.  _and_ should not be used for logical operations: It communicates the wrong intent, it's contrary to generally accepted practices, and it can cause bugs later when the code is modified.  _Just don't do that_.

Comment: The last one is wrong, e.g. `(false if false) and (true if false)` is `nil` (falsy), but `(false || !(false)) && (true || !(false))` is `true`

Comment: @WayneConrad Ruby inherits functional programming aspects from Lisp. All expressions have return value, and you can always perform operations on them. There is no meaningful distinction between the value of an expression and the result of a control flow. When is it, then, according to you that is appropriate to use `and`?

Comment: By the way the problem is that `cond1 if condition` will return `nil`, not true. You could write `!(!cond1 if condition) and !(!cond2 if other_condition)` but I guess that defeats the whole purpose :)

Comment: @sawa - There is a very meaningful distinction in the _precedence_ of `and` vs. `&&`; because of that difference, `&&` is ill suited to flow control, and `and` is ill suited to boolean logic.  Did you know that `and` and `or` have the _same_ precedence?  With simple enough expressions, or with enough parentheses, you can interchange `&&` with `and` and `||` with `or`, but _why_?

Comment: @sawa I agree with you. Using `and`, `or`, `not` is  not inherently wrong, you just have to know about the precedence issues that might arise. However, "never use flow control operators for boolean operations" is a simple rule that will work for most people and prevent them from slipping into frustrating bugs.

Comment: @WayneConrad What do you mean by a later version? The only edit I did after p11y's comment was to cross out the code that had `and` and `if`. There isn't any left with `and` and `if`. What code are you talking about?